# Show checkbox with database value

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I am having trouble with a part of my code. I want the checkbox in the last column to be checked if the corresponding DB value is 1, but something keeps going wrong with my code, anyone who sees what's wrong? It's probably very simple but I can't find it.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum"; 
$myData=mysql_query($sql,$con) ;
?>

<table width="1100" border="1">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">naam</th>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald?</b></th>
</tr>

<?php

$betaald = $record['betaald'];

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {

    echo  "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>" . $record['naam'] . "</td>";
    echo  "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1' ". echo ($betaald==1 ? 'checked' : ''); . " ></td>";
    echo  "</tr>";

    }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);
?>

<table width="1100" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">naam</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald?</b></th>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $record['naam'] ?></td>
            <td> 
                <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1'
                        <?php if($record['betaald'] == 1){ ?>
                            checked="checked"
                        <?php } ?>
                        />
            </td>
        </tr>
   <?php  } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum"; 
$myData=mysql_query($sql,$con) ;
?>

<table width="1100" border="1">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">naam</th>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald?</b></th>
</tr>

<?php



while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {

    $betaald = $record['betaald'];
    echo  "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>" . $record['naam'] . "</td>";
    echo  "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1' ";
    echo $betaald==1 ? 'checked' : '';
    echo " ></td>";
    echo  "</tr>";

    }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

You have assigned `$betaald` value outside the while loop so there is no value in `$betaald`.

I have included `$betaald` inside while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried it without succes. I've noticed the problem is in the line 

echo  "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1' ". echo ($betaald==1 ? 'checked' : ''); . " ></td>";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum";
    $myData= mysql_query($sql) ;
?>

    <table width="1100" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">naam</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald</b></th>
    </tr>

<?php

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
    {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo  $record['naam'] ?></td>
            <td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald' id='betaald' value='1' <?php echo ($record['betaald']==1 ? 'checked' : '')?>> </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

`mysql_query($sql)` no need to define `$con`

> **Note: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

You need several changes in your php and html code. First of all I've some confusion about your code. Let me clear those.

**Point 1 [name='betaald']:** If you have a name like this you will not get multiple selected value.

**Point 2 [id='betaald']:** ID must be unique in a page.

**Point 3 [value='1']:** How will you differ values if all have same value?

so your code should be something like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registered ORDER BY datum"; 
$myData=mysql_query($sql,$con) ;
?>

<table width="1100" border="1">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">naam</th>
<th style="text-align:center; padding:0 10px">betaald?</b></th>
</tr>

    <?php
$betaald = $_POST['betaald'];
$i = 1;
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {

    echo  "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>" . $record['naam'] . "</td>";
    echo  "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='betaald[]' id='betaald".$i."' value='".$record['betaald']."' ";
    if ($record['betaald'] == $betaald)
    {
        echo "checked";
    }
    echo " ></td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
    $i++;
    }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```